# Could not find installable ISAM. Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, isam

I have a access database in web. This file is being uploaded in the web earlier. When I checked the same in web by file manager I could see the file. But when I am trying to read this file using this statement

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
    Data Source=~\httpdocs\Admin\Acessdatabase\ATT2000.mdb;
    Persist Security Info=False;
    Jet OLEDB:Database Password=; 
    providerName=System.Data.OleDb";
```

it is giving me error as **"Cannot find Instalble ISAM"**.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this error, and I've read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805) article back and forth but no vain.

Finally, I've understood that the trouble is something with the security. So, my solution was to use the local (default) **mdw file** (Microsoft Access Workgroup Information) like this:

```
string strConnectionString = 
    "Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';Data Source=" + p_strFileName +
    ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + p_strDBPassword +
    ";Mode=Share Exclusive;Persist Security Info=True;";

// Important part - using mdw file
strConnectionString += "Jet OLEDB:System Database=" + 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") + 
    @"\Microsoft\Access\system.mdw";
```

and use the connection on code:

```
var conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
```