# An unhandled exception for MS Access connection

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to connect to a server in a Windows application in VB.NET. I am using this code

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=//corpopef@162.222.225.78/CRM.mdb;database=User=corpopef;Password=****;"
con.Open()
MsgBox("Database is now open")

con.Close()
'  ftpes://corpopef@162.222.225.78/CM.mdb
MsgBox("Database is now Closed")
```

but i am getting an error saying

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.

plz help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADODB Connection String: Workgroup Information file is Missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458582/adodb-connection-string-workgroup-information-file-is-missing)

Comment: i didnt get u. can u give me the code or tell my mistake plz..

Comment: You didn't get `possible duplicate of`?

Comment: If you follow the link in Bjørn-Roger's comment and read the accepted answer you will find that your connection string is wrong.

Comment: what should be my connection string...?? plz help..

Comment: @megha This web site is not a code-writing service. There are plenty of examples at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) for you to select the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should go look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

If you do go and look at that site, you'll see that the connection string for an [access database with password](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/with-database-password/) should be

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

Whereas what you have is

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=//corpopef@162.222.225.78/CRM.mdb;database=User=corpopef;Password=****;
```

Now, I honestly can't remember if the slashes make a difference (it's been a long time since I've tried connecting to anything like this), but lets assume they do, in which case, the first bit of your connection string is almost correct, reversing the slashes will give you:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\corpopef@162.222.225.78\CRM.mdb;

You then need to declare the database password, which gives you:

```
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=*******;
```

(obviously, unless the database password is 7 *'s, put the password in there)

So your completed connection string would be:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\corpopef@162.222.225.78\CRM.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=*******;
```

Which means your code should be:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\corpopef@162.222.225.78\CRM.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=*******;"
con.Open()
MsgBox("Database is now open")

con.Close()
'  ftpes://corpopef@162.222.225.78/CM.mdb
MsgBox("Database is now Closed")
```

You're likely to get more civil and also more helpful responses if you don't panic and beg for help and actually think about what people are saying in the comments. The main reason I'm helping is because 1) I've got a spare few moments, and 2) I know how upsetting it is when you're at the end of your tether, can't figure something out and just want it done.